# What resistor to use on IGBT

Tags: transistors, igbt

I am planing to use FGH40N60SFD ([here's datasheet](https://storage.ua.prom.st/820848_40n60sfd.pdf)) IGBT transistor as a switch (to connect / disconnect from battery 12V up to 5A). How should I choose resistor to connect to gate? I will be using 5V Arduino to do it.

Comment: Strange choice for switching 12V. Why an IGBT? Have you worked out the likely voltage drop across the  IGBT? Looks like you'll waste more than 10% of the battery power in the switch. what benefits justify such low efficiency?

Comment: Then I shouldn't use transistor at all? Relay? I though it would be more efficient to use transistor because relay use current to stay on.

Comment: How do you get that from my recommending against IGBT?  MOSFET would be a reasonable choice. Relay or solid state relay  (SSR) would also be reasonable choice (SSR would be simple and take very little current to stay on)

Comment: How about IFR3205 MOSFET? I found nothing about voltage drop in it. What is the specification I should be looking for to know whether it is effective or not?

Comment: Mainly RDS(on) at your chosen gate drive voltage. Voltage drop V is I * RDS(on) so if RDS(on) is 10 mOhm (at Vgs=5V) and I is 5A then V = 50mV. A bit better than 1.2V. I won't comment on your suggested one since I'd have to search for its datasheet. Vds(max) and Id(max) are obviously important too but you should have no trouble finding a suitable part. Cottect it as a "low side switch" (useful search term should show you the details)